# SPF ip4 record for servers in auto scaling group?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, spf, autoscaling

I have a set of servers in an ASG behind a load balancer on AWS that are all capable of sending emails. The problem is I need to authorize an IP in our DNS SPF record in order to keep emails from these servers out of spam folder. I am not sure what to do here since the IPs of the servers change periodically due to ASG actions. What can I do to fulfill the SPF requirement?

Comment: You should use AWS SES for outbound email (or a third-party like Sendgrid, if you prefer) for this sort of reason.

Answer (score 2):

SPF has a limit of ten servers, and with "propagation time" (really cache TTL) you can't effectively change the IPs dynamically.

As @ceejayoz says the best solution is to use [AWS Simple Email Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) for outbound email, or something similar like Sendgrid or AuthSMTP. This ensures a single IP or domain name that your email comes from, they're set up properly and managed well, and the costs are relatively negligable.

Answer (score 1):

That is going to be rough due to the propagation time of DNS.  You could instead put these nodes into a private zone and have their outgoing connections traverse a NAT service, which would have an Elastic IP that won't change. If the volume is reasonable you could instead have a dedicated 'smart-host' that acts as a collection point for outgoing emails and also has a EIP.